Cannot redirect http to https for OpenVpn Access Server on GCP
I need some suggestions about how to redirect http to https for OpenVpn Access Server on GCP.
I have tried some methods but none of them worked, include following this tutorial https://openvpn.net/as-docs/tutorials/tutorial--redirect-http-to-https.html#tutorial--how-to-redirect-http-to-https (when i reboot reboot the VM, it said that Connection Failed but when i run the python file, it works properly). When i run this command sudo lsof -i :80, it show that two service( google-osconfig-agent and google-guest-agent) are running at this port, should i disable them?
